# How do i successfully install magento2?

Tags: installation, magento2, magento2.4

I'm getting this error message when I copy and paste the final code block [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgpnm.png)

Steps taken
(1) I've tried rewritting the line of code.
(2) Tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Was expecting for it to work but gave the same error.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your base url into quotes? `--base-url="http://localhost/m246/pub"`

Comment: I was missing this thanks. All of the object strings needed qoutes on all of them.